# Do voters usually follow the advise regarding the choice in the second round of elections given by a candidate who lost in the first round?

Tags: democracy, presidential-election

According to [this article](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/french-election-latest-francois-fillon-calls-supporters-to-vote-emmanuel-macron-a7698236.html), Francois Fillon advised his voters to vote for Emmanuel Macron in the second round of 2017 French Presidential elections.

I have seen this way of telling the voters what to chose in the second rounds on several occasions (both in my native country and abroad) and I am wondering if voters are sensible to such advices.

**Question:** are there any studies that show which counts more: such an advise vs. voters "organic" political preferences?

Comment: Are you wondering whether voters are swayed by these endorsements at all, or whether the effectiveness of endorsement by a first-round candidate is different from endorsements by politicians who dropped out during primaries, politicians in other races, and/or non-politicians?

Comment: @BenVoigt - I am wondering if voters are swayed by these endorsements rather than their own choice. For current French elections, my feeling is that most of the Fillon's voters would vote for Macron anyway, not only because he is "better" or "the right choice", but as a vote against Le Pen.